# How to fix StringBuffer bug

Tags: java, compiler-errors, stringbuffer

i got the message from compiler which is

> The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
>   referenced from required .class files

I'm using `drjava` and `Eclipse Compiler 0.A48.`How to fix it ?
it's my following code:

```
  private StringBuffer secretWord;
  private StringBuffer allLetters;
  private StringBuffer usedLetters;
  private StringBuffer knownSoFar;
  private int numberOfIncorrectTries;
  private int maxAllowedIncorrectTries;

  //Constructor
  public Hangman()
  {
    this.allLetters = new StringBuffer("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    this.maxAllowedIncorrectTries = 6;
    this.numberOfIncorrectTries = 0;
    this.usedLetters = new StringBuffer("");
    this.secretWord = chooseSecretWord();
    this.knownSoFar = new StringBuffer("");
    for(int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++)
    {
      knownSoFar.append('*');
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Paste your entire code.

Comment: Something is wrong with your compiler install. I would check the JDK you are using. Classes/interfaces in `java.lang` shouldn't be missing. BTW Don't use StringBuffer as StringBuilder replaced it more than ten years ago.

Comment: i edited the code

Answer (score 0):

The CharSequence interface was introduced in Java 1.4.  If your compiler thinks it is missing, then the most likely explanations are:

- You are using a really old build platform.  (JDK 1.3.x or ealier)
- Your build platform is damaged, misconfigured or buggy.

I'm afraid I'm not familiar with with DrJava.  However, I did find this bug report that seems to be the same problem:

- https://sourceforge.net/p/drjava/bugs/944/

I would recommend using another IDE.